# Segmentation Fault when I fread a binary file

Tags: c

I am not that good at C, but I have never seen anything like this before.

I have a binary file, `file.bin`, which has one `long` integer followed by a lot of `double` real numbers. So I wrote following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char filename[1000];
    sprintf(filename, "~/file.bin");
    FILE *fp;
    long i;
    double x;

    fp=fopen(filename,"rb");

    fread(&i,sizeof(long),1,fp);

    printf("%ld\n",i);

    for (i=0;i<20;i++){
        fread(&x,sizeof(double),1,fp);
        printf("%le\n",x);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Segmentation violation occurs at the `fread(&i,sizeof(long),1,fp);` I wrote similar codes before in this fashion and they all worked fine, but this is not.

Thanks, in advance, for your answers.

FYI, I am using gcc 3.4.6 on a linux server.

Comment: What value does `fp` contain?

Comment: `fread` expects a non-null file pointer. Please check the result of `fopen`. (The `~` syntax is uderstood by the shell, but might not be recognised by the standard library. Try the full, resolved path.)

Comment: use `const char *filename = "file.bin";`

Comment: @Ôrel: that is not the proper solution. You cannot tell in which folder this executable is located, or from where it is called. The OP *wants* to read from a file in his home folder! (Actually it would be worth looking in to manually translating `~` in the proper path, as it is quite illuminating to find out how it works "under the hood".)

Comment: My comment is about removing the unusefull `sprintf` not about the localisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the file exists and fp is not NULL?!!!

I tried your code and, if the file exists, it runs also if the file contains no data.

I recommend you to insert a control after the file opening:

```
fp=fopen(filename,"rb");
if (fp==NULL) {
    perror("Error ");
    return errno;
}
```

If you use errno remember to include errno.h!

```
#include <errno.h>
```

This patch solves only the error due to the NULL assignement of fp, but shall be better you consider also the errors the fread() function returns if you read beyond the end (and other cases). See fread specifications: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/